# where to put javascript from website template in blazor project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a new Blazor WebAssebly project in VS19 and wanted to add a website template to my project, I downloaded it but was wondering where I should put the JavaScript files it came with.

I currently have them here in my index.html file in wwwroot folder:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>ImmoPlatform.SPA</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="ImmoPlatform.SPA.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- slick slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.js"></script>
    <!-- Price picker slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nouislider.js"></script>
    <!-- mixit slider -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mixitup.js"></script>
    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom js -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
</body>

</html>
```

but when I start my blazor project the javascript doesent seem to load. the CSS I put in the mainlayout.razor file in the Shared folder works file and that CSS came with the template.

Is this the correct place to put them? or should I put them somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem as you. The J/S files must point to the index.html; however, Blazor does not load them automatically – it must use the J/S interoperability, which is complex, and much more so if you do not know the functions that the template has.

At home, I wanted to use Admin LTE, luckily I found a project on GitHub, where they are making a version of this template for Blazor.

https://github.com/sjefvanleeuwen/blazor-adminlte

Hopefully the Blazor team will change this type of operation, since, in my view, it is a setback in the way of doing frontEnd.